# setText in Fragment from MainActivity Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

So I'm trying to populate one `fragment` from another `fragment` with a `button` in my main activity. The main activity is the parent of both `fragments`. 
The layout looks like this

`fragMoney` contains `TextViews` that need to be set

`fragCalculate` contains `EditText` fields that i take input from to set fragMoney's `TextViews` and the `button` that calculates the totals.

`MainActivity`, the parent, is where I'm attempting to do this work.

I get a nice long error message about `null pointer exception` but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. I would venture a guess that its because I'm not declaring something before a certain piece of code. Anyways, here is the code and the logcat.

**Main Activity Button**

```
public void calculateHandler(View view) {
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "calc button");
    dailyView.setText("" + getDaily());
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "getting daily");
    monthlyView.setText("" + getMonthly());
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "getting month");
    annualView.setText("" + getAnnually());
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "getting year");
    totalView.setText("" + getTotal());     
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "getting total");
}
```

**Main Activity Methods**

```
public double getDaily() {

    double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());      
    double packs = Double.parseDouble(numPacks.getText().toString());

    daily = price * packs;

    return daily;
}

public double getMonthly() {
    double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());      
    double packs = Double.parseDouble(numPacks.getText().toString());

    monthly = price * packs * 30.41;

    return monthly;
}

public double getAnnually() {
    double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());      
    double packs = Double.parseDouble(numPacks.getText().toString());   

    annually = (price * packs) * 365;

    return annually;
}

public double getTotal () {
    double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());      
    double packs = Double.parseDouble(numPacks.getText().toString());
    double years = Double.parseDouble(numYears.getText().toString());

    total = (price * packs) * 365 * years;      

    return total;
}
```

**Logcat**

```
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 11 more
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.example.smokin4tomsullivan.MainActivity.getDaily(MainActivity.java:162)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  at com.example.smokin4tomsullivan.MainActivity.calculateHandler(MainActivity.java:199)
03-30 16:27:43.443: E/AndroidRuntime(815):  ... 14 more
```

As always thank you everyone for any help given

**Update Note**

ok so after debugging it appears this line of code:

`double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());`
is giving me the trouble. It's an `EditText` field in the `CalcFrag` set to take the type `numDecimals`, to which at this run i entered 8.7
Any ideas?

**2nd Update**
This is the code that initialized packPrice, its in onCreate

```
EditText packPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.per_pack_Id);
```

**3rd Update** 
this is the code I am running with log.v also see above for modified calcButton

```
public double getDaily() {
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "running getDaily");
    EditText packPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.per_pack_Id);
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", "initialized packPrice");
    double price = Double.parseDouble(packPrice.getText().toString());
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", packPrice.getText().toString());
    String test = ("" + price);
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", test);
    double packs = Double.parseDouble(numPacks.getText().toString());
    String test1 = ("" + packs);
    Log.v("*** DEBUG ***", test1);

    daily = price * packs;

    return daily;
}
```

When I run it before it crashes log.v spits out this

```
03-30 17:34:15.883: V/*** DEBUG ***(1166): calc button
03-30 17:34:15.883: V/*** DEBUG ***(1166): running getDaily
03-30 17:34:15.893: V/*** DEBUG ***(1166): initialized packPrice
03-30 17:34:15.893: V/*** DEBUG ***(1166): 9.9 <-- the values I entered
03-30 17:34:15.893: V/*** DEBUG ***(1166): 9.9 <-- the values I entered
```

Comment: The logcat error message states that the problem occurs on line 162 of MainActivity.java. Which line of code is this? Can you figure out which variable might be null?

Comment: From your update, it appears that either `packPrice` is `null` or the return value of `packPrice.getText()` is. Start by checking if `packPrice` itself is `null` and show the code where it is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception seems pretty clear to me, either `packPrice` or `numPacks` are null or the return from `getText` is null within your `getDaily` method.

You need to figure out which portion of the call is in fact null and work backwards from that.

Comment: hm, could it be because my input types on the `EditText` fields are set to `numberDecimal`? I know that these `EditText` fields have text in them, as i am typing it myself, and in the correct format of 6.50 etc. I will do some `Log.v's` and figure out what's null and get back to you

Comment: Mclver still getting the error but I figured out where, i updated my post

Comment: What is the value when you step through the debugger and is `packPrice` null or `getText`?

Comment: This is probably where you will stop helping me as it goes out of the scope of this question. I set my breakpoints for the debugger but when I try and step into or over my methods/lines it just freaks out. It doesn't display anything. It's obviously my fault but as of right now I have no idea how to use eclipse/android debugger the right way. So to answer your question, I have no idea. I put log.v messages before my methods and lines and it stopped dead just before that line. So i assumed it was the culprit

Comment: That line is the culprit but you need to identify which portion of the line is null. Add separate log lines logging `packPrice` and logging `packPrice.getText' to see which one fails.

Comment: well if I try and log.v `packPrice.getText().toString();` that is where it fails. It will crash the program giving the same errors. The `EditText` field `packPrice` is fine. Somehow the values inside of it are not being passed from my `calcFrag` into my `moneyFrag` and I updated my post to show where packPrice is declared

Comment: Are you certain that within the `onCreate` where you call `EditText packPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.per_pack_Id);` that `packPrice` is not null? Are you storing this as a class level variable and attempting to use it later? Are you finding the view whenever you need it? This is the caveat with lackluster questions, they become troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: Ya, and I apologize, in all honesty I completely understand where your coming from. I updated a 3rd update that should clarify things. It's a small breakthrough. If need be I can just post my 3 files. It's no trouble to me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27253/discussion-between-aaron-mciver-and-irishwhiskey)

Comment: ... non of my messages are popping up in chat... i can see yours

Comment: im just going to accept your answer as it pointed me in the right direction. No idea why chat wont work and at this point I give up

Comment: @IrishWhiskey Interesting... I flagged your comment to see if they can identify if it is in fact an issue with regards to chat not working for you.

Comment: thanks, so if you're still interested, let me know. The app no longer crashes but it doesn't set the Text in the other fragment. Anyways if not it's cool, thanks for the help

Comment: @IrishWhiskey I would ask a new question around your problem, keeps things a bit more granular and makes it easier for people to help you out.